# Rave Reports and Intraweb?

Tags: delphi, memory, report, stream

Anyone have an example of using Rave Reports (PDF output) and Intraweb ? (or even WebBroker) in delphi ?

I'm assuming you write to a memory stream and then output this to the browser.

Any help on Rave Reports/Memory Streams and Intraweb or Webbroker appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are a couple of issues with RAVE in multi-threaded environments. Felix posted some code which does not fully adjust for that. Basically the demo about Rave and IW in Atozed's demos section would work though

DO NOT use Felix' alternative literally - using BDE with IntraWeb will lead to nothing but trouble. BDE is just not designed to be used in server type applications like IW.

Ultimately I recommend either FastReport or Report Builder with Intraweb - both are proven to be working stable with IW